# Iterating over aggregated results with AQL returns null values for expected average/sum values

Tags: arangodb, aql

I would like to execute an AQL query on my arangoDB (2.3.1) instance to compute the delta between two averages (**average_value**) (with **res** possibly being another subquery result):

```
LET last = (FOR r in res
    FILTER DATE_MONTH(r.date) == 1 AND DATE_YEAR(r.date) == 2015
    COLLECT name = r.name INTO g
    RETURN {"name":name,"average_value":AVERAGE(g[*].r[*].value)}
    )
LET current = (FOR r in res
    FILTER DATE_MONTH(r.date) == 2 AND DATE_YEAR(r.date) == 2015
    COLLECT name = r.name INTO g
    RETURN {"name":name,"average_value":AVERAGE(g[*].r[*].value)}
    )
FOR l IN last
    FOR c IN current
         FILTER c.name == l.name
         RETURN {"name":c.name,"delta":c.average_value-l.average_value}
```

But even with just

```
FOR l IN last
    RETURN l
```

I do get the "name" but "average_value" will be null. Is this working as designed or how can I access aggregated values from a subquery?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 2):

Without having access to the data, it seems to me that `.r[*].value` is causing the problem.

Inside the two `FOR` loops in which `r` is defined, `r` is a reference to a single document. Using the expand operator (`[*]`) on a single document will produce `null`, because the `[*]` operator can be used on lists/arrays only.

What you can do instead is to use just `.r.value` instead of `.r[*].value`.
Then the arangodb database should do what you want.

Comment: even with `.r.value`, the iteration over the aggregated results with `FOR l IN last RETURN l` returns null for average_value. By the way, `RETURN last` will output the average values correctly. It is only with the FOR-LOOP, which will return null values for averages/sums

Comment: The modified query (with `.r.value` instead of `.r[*].value`) works fine for me in 2.3 and 2.4. However, I don't have access to the data in your collection so I don't know on what kind of data you run the query on. Here is my setup for which the query returned averages and differences: `db._create("res"); for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { db.res.save({ date: (new Date(1420500000000 + 5000000000 * Math.random()).toISOString()), name: "test" + (i % 10), value: Math.random() * 100 }); }`

Comment: @stj it doesn't work for me with r.value. My data structure is :

[code]
    {
       "inst": 'A',
       "min": 3,
       "max": 4,
       "sum":10
    },
 
 {
       "inst": 'B',
       "min": 2,
       "max": 3,
       "sum":20
    }

[/code]
and the Query is :
var query = "LET xx = (FOR m in raw COLLECT mm = m.inst INTO g RETURN {'inst': mm, 'max':max(FLATTEN(g[*].m.max)),'min':min(FLATTEN(g[*].m.min)), 'sum':sum(FLATTEN(g[*].m[*].sum))}) for a in xx return a"

Comment: I guess all the `*`s in the previous comment got lost. Please note that code fragments should be included in backticks, not `[code]...[/code]`. `*` characters outside code sections will lead to italic or bold formatting and the `*` chars themselves being not printed.

Comment: Revisiting this issue: I think there is an issue if there's a `COLLECT...INTO` statement producing aggregates in a subquery, which itself is followed by other statements than `RETURN` ,for example `LET values = (FOR ... COLLECT ... INTO ... RETURN ...) FOR v IN values RETURN v`. In this case, the sub-attributes in the result produced by `COLLECT INTO` may have wrong attribute name, so accessing them with their correct attribute name will produce `null`. This was just fixed. The fix will be available in 2.5.6 and 2.6.0 stable.

Comment: Until then, the workaround will be to move the `COLLECT...INTO` out of the subquery, or not follow up the subquery will other statements than `RETURN`.

Comment: I am using the result of the subquery to insert the documents. 

`FOR  a in xx INSERT a in yy`

Any suggestion how to do that with that single query.

Comment: Interestingly If I add a bad function after 'sum' like following I get the desired result:

`, 'avg':average([g[*].m[*].min, g[*].m[*].max])`

Comment: Is it possible to try this with a 2.6.0? It should be fixed in there so all these queries should work.